# Can Windows 7 acquire DNS from IPv6-Router-Advertisement?

Tags: windows, dns, ipv6

I am playing around with IPv6. Usually, Router Advertisements transmit the prefix and gateway for SLAAC. Since DNS is quite essential, since 2010 RA should also be (optionally) able to transmit the DNS Server as well. However, Windows 7 was released in 2009 and so I am wondering if Windows 7 is able to get the DNS Server from the RA or if it needs at least DHCPv6 in a stateless setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the current Windows implementations can use DNS options from RA packets. It's frustrating, but Windows is the only major platform that doesn't support that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you - by chance - have any source for this? I searched a bit but couldn't find anything clear. Everywhere it was just general that you need DHCP, nowhere mentioned it should work also without.

Comment: My source is Microsoft staff that I talk to at conferences, and personal experience. It's hard to prove a negative...

Comment: Well, I was just hoping to read a little bit about why it is that MS decided not to implement it (yet?).

Comment: I have never heard a reason, even from people working at MS, so it remains a mystery :)

Comment: Just want to add that support for RDNSS was implemented in Windows 10 starting from Creators Update (version 1703).